# design UI of app using tablview in swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, scroll, tableview

I want UI of my app to be similar like as shown in below image.

[image]

Using tableview i'm able to get **Payment,Delivery,Build Team** options as shown in image but for **Build Profile,Manage Menu**.. how do i do it using tableview ?
If not tableview for these options then what other control i can try.

Comment: Show us what you've tried so far.

Comment: There are lot of ways to do the same.:)

Comment: try .xib to add view.

Comment: You can add two UIViews for Build Profile and Manage Menu

Comment: Use different cell types for those two items. Slightly taller and with an inner view with the drop shadow

Comment: Create 2 different `Cell`. For 1st `cell`, add 2 `UIView`, 1st is **Build Profile** and 2nd `UIView` is **Manage Menu** and for 2nd `cell` you just need to set `checkMark` or `greater than` image programatically.

Answer (score 0):

this type of UI you are looking for and you can easily get by creating different Cell classes

**UI Output :**

[image]

**Required Code**

Step 1 - Create different Xib of table cell

```
class viewWithArrow: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var headerLabel: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}

class viewWithShadow: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var shadowView: UIView!{
        didSet{
            shadowView.addShadowToView(color: .black)
        }
    }
    @IBOutlet weak var headerLabel: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

Adding Shadow Effect :

```
extension UIView {
    func addShadowToView(color:UIColor)
    {
        self.layer.shadowColor = color.cgColor
        self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.2
        self.layer.masksToBounds = false
        self.clipsToBounds = false
        self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)
        self.layer.shadowRadius = 5
    }
}
```

View controller

```
class ViewController: UIViewController
{
    var dataArray : [String] = ["11","22","33","44","55","66"]
    @IBOutlet weak var homeVcTableView: UITableView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        homeVcTableView.register(UINib(nibName: "viewWithShadow", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "viewWithShadow")
        homeVcTableView.register(UINib(nibName: "viewWithArrow", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "viewWithArrow")
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        self.homeVcTableView.delegate = self
        self.homeVcTableView.dataSource = self
    }
}

extension ViewController : UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate
{
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return dataArray.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        switch indexPath.row {
        case 0,1:
            let cell = self.homeVcTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "viewWithShadow", for: indexPath) as! viewWithShadow
            cell.headerLabel.text = dataArray[indexPath.row]
            return cell
        default:
            let cell = self.homeVcTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "viewWithArrow", for: indexPath) as! viewWithArrow
            cell.headerLabel.text = dataArray[indexPath.row]
            return cell
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return self.homeVcTableView.frame.size.height*0.1
    }


}
```

**Working code link -** https://drive.google.com/open?id=18mSlWAU_e4XElox4H-oTpqg8clD_HKwu